# Setup domain name on GCE via cloud DNS

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dns

We have followed  [this instruction](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/lamp/setting-up-dns#mapping_your_domain_name_using_cloud_dns)  to use cloud DNS to set up host name of our GCE instance, which external IP is static.  But we still cannot look up the domain name of our GCE instance from the internet after waiting several days. Is there anything that we miss when we setup cloud DNS??

Comment: is this still an issue?

Comment: Yes... we are still not able to find our domain name. The name servers that we use is identical to the ones suggested by "Registrar Setup" link in Cloud DNS...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cloud DNS as the Name Server too?

If yes, please follow the steps here to update your domain registrar's name server setting
https://cloud.google.com/dns/update-name-servers

Comment: It seems that Cloud DNS has already assigned us the correct name servers at the very beginning. However, we are still not able to find our domain name from the internet...

Answer (score 0):

Is the Cloud DNS name server reflected in your domain registrar's name server setting?  What is the dig response for your domain search ?

Comment: The Cloud DNS name servers (NS) are exactly the same as the ones suggested by registar's setup. The dig response for my domain search only shows the following authorization section : ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.   5 IN SOA a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1433471810 1800 900 604800 86400

Answer (score 0):

To set up a domain name on GCE via cloud dns, you need to set up a Cloud DNS managed zone and then setting up Address (A) and Canonical Name (CNAME) records for the domain. Please see below procedure on how to set up Cloud DNS managed zone, A record and CNAME records:

Create a managed public zone [1].

A managed zone is a container for DNS records of the same DNS name suffix. A managed zone has a set of name servers that accept and responds to queries. Create a new managed public zone:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_new_record

Create a new record for A record [2].

[2] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/quickstart#create_a_cname_record

Create a CNAME record [3].

The record update will take some time to propagate depending on the time-to-live (TTL) values in your zone. You can verify that the DNS records are working by visiting the domain name and confirming that the domain resolves to your IP address.